# Why strange characters appear on the website but not on html editor?

Tags: html, google-chrome, sublimetext3

I copy pasted the following html code from a textbook into a text editor (Sublime). Then opened the html page in Google Chrome as shown in the image below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="processorder.php" method="post"><table border="0">
            <tr bgcolor="#cccccc">
              <td width="150">Item</td>
              <td width="15">Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Tires</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="tireqty" size="3"
                 maxlength="3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Oil</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="oilqty" size="3"
                 maxlength="3" /></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
              <td>Spark Plugs</td>
              <td align="center"><input type="text" name="sparkqty" size="3"
                 maxlength="3" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit Order" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The "Â" a-circumflex characters at the top of the page are not supposed to be there. Why is it that Google Chrome displays them, but not the text editor?

[image]

Comment: I copied that exact code into a text document on my machine and opened it in Chrome. I also tried with [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/web_project). Neither showed those characters. Maybe something with Sublime? What character set is it set to save as? UTF-8? ANSI?

Comment: Just checked again, it is using UTF-8

Comment: Unfortunately, then, I have no idea. I was unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: SOLVED: The characters appeared on the webpage because they were in fact part of the html document. However, they were not being displayed on sublime because I was using UTF-8  and it displays them as space characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: The strange characters appear because they are part of the html document. They were not being displayed because the text editor was using UTF-8 encoding.

The character "Â" is called a-circumflex and it is displayed as an empty space " " when using UTF-8 encoding, which is the default encoding of Sublime text 3.

Comment: We also had this behaviour in Atom, VS2015 and various other IDEs. The only editor that showed the errant characters was Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

From [Chrome help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95290?hl=en-GB)

If you are seeing strange characters on chrome, try to fix the character encoding settings:

1. Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select More Tools.
3. Select Encoding.
4. Pick one of the encodings listed or choose Auto-detect. If you choose to auto-detect, Google Chrome analyses the content on the page to recommend the most suitable encoding. For the fastest browsing experience, we recommend turning off the auto detect mode after you leave the web page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The strange characters disappeared afterwards. However, the space the used to occupy is still there, thus the table is being displayed a below from where it is supposed to be. This is what google chrome inspect tool shows: http://i.imgur.com/Soj1N7f.png